Is safe to ask passwords in Elementor Widget Controls?
I'm building an Elementor Widget to allow users to modify files in a FTP server.
Is it safe to use TEXTAREA Elementor Widget Controls to make users enter the server password?
If not, how can i do?

What do you mean by "safe"? Asking people to modify files over FTP via a WordPress plugin/control by itself generally doesn't sound too safe. As a user, I'd be wary of such of things if I didn't know the plugin author because they might inadvertently log my password somewhere and expose the FTP to everyone on the planet.

It's a plugin for my site. I need to edit a file stored in an ftp server using wp because it can give me a nice ui. I want to avoid exposing my password to everyone.
